# Alter settings.xml from a maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

Is it possible to access content of user `settings.xml` file from a maven plugin Mojo ?

And if so, how ?

I would like to alter this file in order to put in some user-specific configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for reading the `Settings` Object see [khmarbaise's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552415/alter-settings-xml-from-a-maven-plugin/5553190#5553190), and for writing the modified settings back, use a `SettingsWriter`:

```
/**
 * @component role="org.apache.maven.settings.io.SettingsWriter"
 */
private SettingsWriter settingsWriter;
```

Comment: Never do such a thing. I would kill such an Maven Plugin which changes my settings.xml file.

Comment: @khmarbaise Even if it is during a kind of "wizard" phase ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I agree, but that's what the OP asked for :-)

Answer (score 3):

This can simply be achieved by injecting the Settings into your Mojo:

```
/**
 * @parameter default-value="${settings}"
 */
private Settings settings;
```